# regarding comparing matrix including words/characters

Tags: r

I have two matrix extracted from different csv files,

One is like

```
> matrix1[1:6,]
     V1        V2
 1   atheism 1.0000000
 2       rec 1.0000000
 3       alt  1.0000000
 4  baseball 1.0000000
 5     sport 1.0000000
 6    season 0.4934226
```

Another is

```
>matrix2[1:6,]
         V1        V2
 1       alt 1.0000000
 2   atheism 1.0000000
 3  baseball 1.0000000
 4       rec 1.0000000
 5     sport 1.0000000
 6         c 0.4934226
```

What I want to do is to compare two matrix, this is what I did

```
mapply(as.data.frame(test1),as.data.frame(test2),FUN=function(v1,v2) all(v2==v2))
        V1   V2 
       TRUE TRUE
```

However, what I need is to capture the difference in the first column between the two data set, but  what I did failed to capture the  difference in string, how to modify my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try:

```
union(test1[, 1] , test2[, 1])    #the same (together)
intersect(test2[, 1], test1[, 1]) #overlap
union(test1[, 1] , test2[, 1]) [!union(test1[, 1] , test2[, 1]) %in% intersect(test2[, 1], test1[, 1])]
setdiff(test1[, 1] , test2[, 1])  #diff in set 1
setdiff(test2[, 1] , test1[, 1])  #diff in set 2
```